# ui-router, url changes, does hit the controller, content wont load, only on reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I got a sub state that is suppose to load content into a `ui-view` called `ui-solution`. It does so while the user is in the flow of creating something called "solution". The strange part is that once that is saved and the user revisit a specific part of the process that calls that same sub state it does not load the content. Can anybody spot anything wrong with this code that could cause this inconsistent behaviour? Just so I can rule this out and start looking elsewhere.

- the url change
- the url has the same parameters
- on reload of the page the right content is loaded in that `ui-view``

The setup of the page is

`ui-view`
 - tabs
 -- `ui-view="ui-solution"`

```
$stateProvider.state('analyse', {
            url: '/analyse/:id',
            data: {
                solution: false
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/a/a.html',
            controller: 'Analisys'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('analyse.solution', {
            url: '/solution',
            data: {
                solution: true
            },
            views: {
                'ui-solution': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/a/s/s.html',
                    controller: 'Analisys'
                }
            }
        });
```

`ui-view="ui-solution"` is present in `a.html` one of the tabs there

Comment: i had the same problem you inherit from the analyse state and it load the a.html first and there is no ui-view there

Comment: I have a specific view called "ui-solution", so that shouldn't matter right? I also already tried to add just a `ui-view` with no name also. @Erez

Comment: i mean it first init the a.html and from what i understand it load that view and look for the ui-view solution inside the a.html or inside the first ui-view( the empty one)

Comment: try this one https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views or this https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Answer (score 0):

you try to load nested view and is not in your parent view so it cant loaded - i had the same problem
i suggest to look at this and also the 2 link i sent on the comment

```
$stateProvider
       .state('analyse', {
            url: '/analyse/:id',
            data: {
                solution: false
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/a/a.html',
            //controller: 'Analisys' better using ng-controller in the html instead of here
        })
        .state('analyse.solution', {
            url: '/solution',
            data: {
                solution: true
            },
            views: {
                'ui-solution': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/a/s/s.html'
                }
            }
        });
```

and your a.html should look like

```
<div ng-controller="Analisys as ctrl">
    <h1 ui-serf="analisys.solution">should load the nested view</h1>
    <div ui-view="ui-solution"></div>//here should see the nested html
</div>
```

and index.html should have

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

hope it will help you

btw

you dont need the `ui-view="solution"` cause its automatically refer to the ui-view inside (unless you have few

so you can do so

```
 $stateProvider
           .state('analyse', {
                url: '/analyse/:id',
                data: {
                    solution: false
                },
                templateUrl: 'app/components/a/a.html'
                //controller: 'Analisys' better using ng-controller in the html instead of here
            })
            .state('analyse.solution', {
                url: '/solution',
                data: {
                    solution: true
                },                    
                templateUrl: 'app/components/a/s/s.html'
            });
```

and a.html

```
<div ng-controller="Analisys as ctrl">
    <h1 ui-serf="analisys.solution">should load the nested view</h1>
    <div ui-view></div>//here should see the nested html
</div>
```